# How do I track changes to a variable in Postgresql database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, e-commerce

I have a postgresql table which stores the inventories of several products in an ecommerce store. When customers buy (return) items, each item's inventory is decremented (incremented) to reflect the transaction.

I am trying to write an analytics tool which shows when an item was changed and the quantity change - essentially a time series of that particular inventory item.

Can someone please point me to a resource to help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Typically, you would write a trigger for this.  When you detect an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`, you calculate `NEW.quantity - OLD.quantity` and then insert that in to your time-series table

Comment: So if the ecommerce platform has webhooks, would I set a webhook to activate a script which does the `INSERT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would add triggers to your tables.  Suppose you have a `inventory` table and a `history` table:

```
create table inventory (id serial primary key, product_id int, quantity int);
create table history (id serial primary key, event_time timestamp not null default now(), product int, delta int);
```

You can create a trigger function and a corresponding trigger:

```
edb=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_history() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO history (product, delta) VALUES (OLD.product_id, NEW.quantity - OLD.quantity);
  RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    INSERT INTO history (product, delta) VALUES (NEW.product_id, NEW.quantity);
  RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
CREATE FUNCTION
edb=# CREATE TRIGGER trigger_inventory_change
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON inventory
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_history();
CREATE TRIGGER
```

Then, for every change in the `inventory` table, you will get an event added to the `history` table:

```
edb=# insert into inventory values (1,1,100);
INSERT 0 1
edb=# select * from history;
 id |        event_time         | product | delta 
----+---------------------------+---------+-------
  2 | 15-NOV-19 00:38:29.204491 |       1 |   100
(1 row)

edb=# insert into inventory values (2,10,100);
INSERT 0 1
edb=# select * from history;
 id |        event_time         | product | delta 
----+---------------------------+---------+-------
  2 | 15-NOV-19 00:38:29.204491 |       1 |   100
  3 | 15-NOV-19 00:38:58.01209  |      10 |   100
(2 rows)
edb=# update inventory set quantity = quantity - 2 where product_id = 1;
UPDATE 1
edb=# update inventory set quantity = quantity - 20 where product_id = 10;
UPDATE 1
edb=# update inventory set quantity = quantity + 20 where product_id = 1;
UPDATE 1
edb=# select * from history
edb-# ;
 id |        event_time         | product | delta 
----+---------------------------+---------+-------
  1 | 15-NOV-19 00:38:29.204491 |       1 |   100
  2 | 15-NOV-19 00:38:58.01209  |      10 |   100
  3 | 15-NOV-19 00:40:01.121778 |       1 |    -2
  4 | 15-NOV-19 00:40:09.403276 |      10 |   -20
  5 | 15-NOV-19 00:40:17.425085 |       1 |    20
(5 rows)
```

I didn't add a case where a `DELETE` happens, but it's the same idea